# Doctrine find multiple by array of composite primary keys

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, composite-key, findby

Is there in Doctrine2 any ways to find pack of entities by array of composite primary keys?

```
$primaryKeys = [ 
    ['key1'=>'val11', 'key2'=>'val21'], 
    ['key1'=>'val12', 'key2'=>'val22'] 
];
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add your custom method to a repository. For example:

```
$repository = $em->getRepository('Application\Entity\Class');
$repository->findByPrimaryKeys();
```

And in your `Application\Entity\Class` repository:

```
/**
 * Find entity by primary keys.
 *
 * @param Parameters[] $array
 * @return Paginator
 */
public function findByPrimaryKeys(array $array)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('e');

    foreach($array as $index => $keys){
        $key1 = $index * 2 + 1;
        $key2 = $index * 2 + 2;
        $qb->orWhere(
            $qb->expr()->andX(
                $qb->expr()->eq('e.key1', '?'.$key1), 
                $qb->expr()->eq('e.key2', '?'.$key2)
            )
        );
        $qb->setParameter($key1, $keys['key1']);
        $qb->setParameter($key2, $keys['key2']);
    };
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Maybe there are other ways, but this works and results in following DQL query:

```
SELECT e FROM Application\Entity\Class e WHERE 
    (e.key1= ?1 AND e.key2= ?2) 
OR 
    (e.key1= ?3 AND e.key2 = ?4)
```